# update mysql database according to the current values in it

Tags: php, mysql

How do I update the database according to the current values in it. I currently have the following -

```
mysqli_query($con,
"UPDATE Tasks
SET completed = CASE WHEN completed == 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
WHERE inde=$q");
```

The above doesn't work but when I try to do

```
mysqli_query($con,
"UPDATE Tasks
SET completed = 1
WHERE inde=$q");
```

it changes the value when ever it is 0 which is correct but I also want to change it to 0 when it is 1. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 8, accepted):

that should be:

```
UPDATE  Tasks set completed= IF(completed=1, 0, 1) WHERE inde=$q LIMIT 1
```

limit 1, if inde is a unique index, speeds up the update (minuscule for small tables, may be worth while for large ones)

... Limit 1 probably does nothing and may be a bad idea.
[Is there any point using MySQL "LIMIT 1" when querying on indexed/unique field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848390/is-there-any-point-using-mysql-limit-1-when-querying-on-indexed-unique-field)

Comment: Curious where you get `LIMIT 1` from ;-)

Comment: "if inde is a unique index, speeds up the update" --- do you think so? I've always thought mysql's optimizer is smart enough to see that the index is unique thus stopping searching after a row is found, hmhm

Comment: you could be right, its a habit i picked up, research suggest, it does nothing, i'll try break this habit, after the drinking\smoking\womanising ones.

Answer (score 1):

```
CASE WHEN completed == 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

This should be:

```
CASE WHEN completed = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

or:

```
CASE completed WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though this question is already answered, however, I just wanted to propose the quicked and shortest answer provided that completed only holds 0s and 1s.

```
UPDATE Tasks set completed=!completed WHERE inde=$q
```

Note the `NOT(!)` operator which will toggle the value itself i.e. change 1s to 0s and 0s to 1s.