# How to speed up PDO query

Tags: php, mysql, performance, pdo

I have products database table(tabl_products) with more than **55 millions** of rows(products) and iam using **PDO query** to display each prduct from tabl_products table, So here is my query table structre and select query..

```
id | pr_name | pr_description | pr_qntty | pr_price
```

```
$pr_id = (int)$_GET['id'];
$select_pr = $con->prepare("SELECT pr_name, pr_description, pr_price FROM tabl_products WHERE id=:pr_id");
$select_pr->bindParam(":pr_id", $pr_id);
$select_pr->execute();
if(!($select_pr->rowCount()))
{
   include '404.php'; exit();
}
$fetch_pr = $select_pr->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo $pr_name = $fetch_pr['pr_name'].'<br/>';
echo $pr_description = $pr_description['pr_description'].'<br/>';
echo $pr_price = $fetch_all['pr_price'];
```

Above query will take 2 to 3 minutes to display a single product information.

So how can I display a single product information within 5 to 10 seconds?

(from comment)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tabl_products (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    pr_name varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
    pr_description varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
    pr_qntty varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
    pr_price varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Is the `id` column indexed?

Comment: id collumn is AUTO_INCREMENT and it is PRIMARY KEY

Comment: How many rows are in the table?

Comment: Exactly 55090297 of rows in tabl_products table

Comment: It should take only only a fraction of a second, even if there were a billion rows.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE tabl_products`; something odd is going on.

Comment: Please print out the value of `rowCount` -- It should be 1, but if it is not, that will be a clue (a puzzling clue).

Comment: @RickJames here it's
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tabl_products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pr_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `pr_description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `pr_qntty` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `pr_price` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: yes @RickJames,  value of rowCount is 1

Comment: Can you turn on the general log to see what query (or queries) are executed?

Comment: How can i turn on the general log in cpanel ?

Comment: A complete guess, but if you're running CPanel, I'm wondering if you're just on a shared server, which is either oversubscribed, or grossly lacking in specification?

Answer (score 2):

I recreated similar database using MySQL 5.7.20, filled about 55000000 of rows with dummy data, and query like this:

`SELECT * FROM stackoverflow_test.tabl_products WHERE id=12345678;`

returns result very quickly on my (decent) PC (shows 0.000s in MYSQL Workbench).

I can give you a few ideas that can make you identify the problem. First, there are a few bugs in your code.

```php
echo $pr_name = $fetch_pr['pr_name'].'<br/>';
echo $pr_description = $pr_description['pr_description'].'<br/>';
echo $pr_price = $fetch_all['pr_price'];
```

`$pr_description` should be replaced with `$fetch_pr`

`$fetch_all` should be replaced with `$fetch_pr`

Maybe there is something else in your php file that makes execution so slow. Try to execute minimal file, or use MySQL Workbench (or similar tool) to make sure it's not the issue with http server or php (maybe the query runs fast, but fetching is slow, or there are other problems?).

Especially with such big database you need to make sure indexes are used. In MySQL you can do it by adding `EXPLAIN`(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html) in front of your query, i.e.:

`EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM stackoverflow_test.tabl_products WHERE id=12345678;`

then analyze fields **possible_keys** and **key**, which should include name of your index (PRIMARY). If MySQL is not using index, then adding `` USE INDEX (`PRIMARY`) `` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html) statement to your query should help, but you should investigate why it isn't used by default.

FYI when I added `` IGNORE INDEX (`PRIMARY`) `` just to check query execution time without index, the query runs for about 30 seconds instead of a fraction of second.

These is also a possiblility that the server is overloaded or not powerfull enough, but with index your query should be very fast anyway.

User [Your Common Sense](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285587/your-common-sense) suggested that even if index is used it may be too big to fit into memory, so it is read from disk which is slow. You may want to check the size of index and compare it with available memory and (if required) adjust MySQL memory settings accordingly.

Comment: I think you're barking the wrong tree. EXPLAIN won't give you any clue. it should be innodb stats and memory status on the db server

Comment: EXPLAIN will tell if indexes are used for this particular query. If they are, you can do further investigation, but if they aren't you may "encourage" MySQL to use indexes with USE INDEX (and investigate why index is not used by default).I know that my answer is not full solution to the problem, but it allows to eliminate  some of the possible causes

Comment: Yes, unlike the other one, by itself it's a good answer and it may help someone else. But in this particular case, it's very hard to believe that a primary key is not used. Most likely there is not enough RAM for the indexes.

Comment: I do agree it looks unlikely for such query. I'm going to include your suggestion in my answer if you don't mind.

Answer (score -2):

As your `id` is unique (primary key), you can add `LIMIT 1`. Because, otherwise, even when your product is found once, PDO will continue to look other products with that particular id.

So your query becomes :

```
SELECT pr_name, pr_description, pr_price FROM tabl_products WHERE id=:pr_id LIMIT 1
```

Try and tell us how long it takes :)

PS: it is used by Doctrine ORM for example:

- line 195, parameter $load in position 6, of http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityRepository.html#183-196
- using method ->load() of BasicEntityPersister http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.Persisters.Entity.BasicEntityPersister.html#705-725

Comment: Hello, why do you think it makes no sense ? Could you develop ? Did you try with and without LIMIT 1 on a 55 millions objects table ? Thank you

Comment: It makes no sense because MySQL's query planner already does this internally. It's smart enough to know what a `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY` key means. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848390/is-there-any-point-using-mysql-limit-1-when-querying-on-indexed-unique-field